# Difference in *.JS files opened with cURL and in Browser

Tags: javascript, curl

If I open this .JS file ([link text](http://www.ss.lv/js/2010-08-18/19197/VnQIFU5hQVgbfwkdSH9BVEp8AVASIQ==.js)) in Browser I get back following in browser window:

```
var PHONE_CNT=2;var PHONE_CNT2=0;var PHONE_CNT3=0;var EMAIL_CNT=2;var SHOW_CNT=1795;var PH_c="";var PH_1=0;var PH_2=0;var PH_3=0;
PH_1 = "JUQyJUFCJThDJUM5JThFJUQzJTgzeSVDMiVEQyVCQ2ElQkUlREQlQzglOUUlOTR6JUE2bSVCN3ElOUIlRTglQzQlQkYlODUlRDklQjIlQzglQjclQUE=";
```

If I open the same file using cURL or ?php (file_get_contents) then the content differs:

```
var PHONE_CNT=0;var PHONE_CNT2=0;var PHONE_CNT3=0;var EMAIL_CNT=0;var SHOW_CNT=1;var PH_c="";var PH_1=0;var PH_2=0;var PH_3=0; 
PH_1 = "JUQyJUFCJThDJUM5JThGJUMyJTg0JTlBJUJBJUM3JUJEdSVDMCVDRCVDOCVFNSU4RiU3RiVBNiVBOSVCOCU4MyU5MCVEOA==";
```

The difference is **PH_1** value.
I tried to set different options for cURL but nothing helps. Any idea how to get .JS file content using cURL same as what I get when using browser.

Thank you in advace.

Answer (score 2):

The server must be generating a different PH1 value based on some request parameters. You'll have to trace out the HTTP headers from both requests to see what causes the difference, e.g. setting up a local proxy such as http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ and making both requests through that.

It could be some combination of the user agent, accepts headers, cookies or the IP or country you're connecting from that's makign the difference - without knowing what the server logic is (or understanding what the different PH1 values mean) we can't really help you sorry.

Comment: Indeed, must have to do with the request parameters everything that I've tried received the exact same data. PH1 is Base64 encoded, url quoted(WTF?) binary stuff.

Comment: Yes, I meant to mention I'd tried using a browser and wget with varied user agent strings and got his first result every time.

Comment: Oh, sorry, wasn't meaning to draw a distinction - I wouldn't expect wget to anything differently than curl, it's just I had wget installed here but not curl. But if it works, great!

Answer (score 0):

Curl just gets the data from the server, **it does not interpret javascript**. If you want to interpret the javascript from the webpage, you'll have to use a javascript engine as spidermonkey.

Comment: No I do not want to execute it, just to see the content of script. @Rup's idea with wget helped.